# TypeError: object of type 'Trending' has no len() and Trending() takes no arguments in Python

Tags: python, tiktok-api

I have this code which I took from the davidteather/TikTok-Api documentation and website. There are two problems that I am facing. The first one is "TypeError: Trending() takes no arguments" which is caused by the "`tiktoks = api.trending(count=count)`" module in my code. And the second problem which is "TypeError: object of type 'Trending' has no len()" is caused by the "`for i in range(len(tiktoks)):`" module. The code its self is from [this website](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/download-tiktoks-with-python-dcbd79a5237f) Maybe @David Teather knows the answer

```
from typing_extensions import Self
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
import string
import random

from pathlib import Path

did=''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for num in range(19))
verifyFp="verify_YOUR_VERIFYFP_HERE"
api = TikTokApi(custom_verifyFp=verifyFp, custom_device_id=did)
#print(api.trending())
count = 100

tiktoks = api.trending(count=count)

Path("downloads").mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for i in range(len(tiktoks)):
    data = api.get_Video_By_TikTok(tiktoks[i])# bytes of the video
    with open("downloads/{}.mp4".format(str(i)), 'wb') as output:
        output.write(data)
```

Comment: The first print print(api.trending()) works properly?

Comment: yes @SerSergious it do3es work porperly